# Проблема с обновлением Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Только что обновился до версии Gradle 4.1. И при сборке проекта вылетает ошибка такого рода.Где может быть проблема? Или как откатится до Gradle предыдущей версии?

```
>Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
>
>Gradle sync failed: 
Cause: com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kombo.eplog"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7', changing: true
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.u-mass:lastfm-java:0.1.2'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.+'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Buildscript

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Текстом ошибку приведите.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Логи?

Comment: То, что вы скинули картинкой, скиньте ещё текстом. Так люди смогут найти этот вопрос из поисковиков, если столкнуться с такой же проблемой.

Comment: Хмм... у меня тоже схожая проблема с новым gradle, убил несколько часов потом откатился назад на старую версию

Comment: @Barmaley А как откатится на старую версию?

Comment: @Serhiy если не затруднит, скиньте что у вас в build.gradle

Comment: @Serhiy обновил ответ

Comment: Скинул. Но со старым Gradle всё было ок)

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632662/android-studio-warning-using-incompatible-plugins-for-the-annotation-processing

Comment: Я уже всё перепробывал. Ничего не помогает. Как вернуть старый Gradle потому как я у же замучился?

Comment: У вас как минимум неверно подключен butterknife: и версии разные, и apt '...' в зависимостях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас кроме неправильного подключения butterknife и с другими либами тоже неверно. Необходимо compile заменить на implementation или api (или compileOnly для findbugs например). и для тестов тоже самое. Внимательно почитайте [гайд по миграции от Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) там расписана каждая конфигурация

Comment: Да вы правы, только что на английском stackoverflow находил  подобное. Кому интересно вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084251/android-studio-3-0-canary-1-annotation-processor-error

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решен следующим образом. В defaultConfig добавить следующий код.

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
```

+ Читать Оф. документацию, т.к у меня butterknife  был подключен неверно